# Creating slideshow from a map with images

Tags: php

I have cms where I can upload pictures into a map.
I also have a slideshow where I have manually put some pictures in. But I want the slideshow to randomly take a picture that I have uploaded.
All my pictures that I upload start with "beeld_" followed with a random nummer

```
<div id="mygallery" class="stepcarousel">
    <div class="belt">
        <div class="panel">
            <?  echo'<img src="'.$root.'/cms/files/slider/fotos/'.'beeld_'. [?] .'.png" alt="" />'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="<?=$root?>/cms/files/slider/fotos/beeld_2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="<?=$root?>/cms/files/slider/fotos/beeld_3.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="<?=$root?>/cms/files/slider/fotos/beeld_4.png">
        </div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want only first random picture or all?

Comment: I want them all to be random pictures. The second panel works but it's not handy to manually change the names of the .png.

Comment: First you list all the images in your folder, then pick 4 random and finally create the html layout for your slideshow

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like `rand(0, 10);` (Note: number 10 can be replaced with highest number of image you have e.g. if your image name has beeld_50 you can use `rand(0, 50` and no image sequence is missing.  you can set value of `$i` for number of slides you want to display)

```
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    echo '<div class="panel">';
    echo '<img src="' . $root . '/cms/files/slider/fotos/beeld_'. rand(0, 10) .'.png" />';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This solution works of you list all files in the folder, but this won't work if a user can delete files and upload more.. considdering you need to change the max rand value all the time..

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you should just list all the images / files you have using `scandir` or an other function:

```
$images = array_diff(scandir($your_directory), array('..', '.'));
```

This gives you an array with all the files listed in that directory, after you did this, you could build your slidesshow panels again doing something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_panels; $i++){
    echo '<div class="panel">';
    echo '<img src="' . $root . '/cms/files/slider/fotos/'. $images[rand(0, (count($images)-1)] .'" />';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Not that you need to do `(count($images)-1)` , if you don't it could be possible you would go out of the arrays bounds.. .

Comment: that is a better idea but a minor change `$images[rand(0, (count($images)-1)]` should be `$images[rand(2, (count($images)-1)]` as 0 and 1 will be "." and ".."